# javascript this function in a function

Tags: javascript, this

I'm trying to use this. inside of a function that creates an object. But it doesn't appear to work.

```
function enemy(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = 32;
        this.height = 32;
        this.img = new Image();
        this.ready = false;
        this.img.onload = function() {
            this.ready = true;
        }
        this.img.src = "images/barney.png";
    }
```

this.ready is never set to true, I need so that I can render the image. Any ideas?

Comment: `this` in that function refers to an image. `console.log(this)` to see that.

Comment: Thanks, yea I kinda realized that, but was wondering what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is no longer pointing to the same object as it was in the first function, try assigning `var self = this`:

```
function enemy(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = 32;
        this.height = 32;
        this.img = new Image();
        this.ready = false;
        var self = this; // note here how we save the value of `this`
        this.img.onload = function() {
            self.ready = true; // and use that saved `this` here
        }
        this.img.src = "images/barney.png";
    }
```

You need to do this because the value of `this` changes when you're inside the `onload` method.

As @JamesMcLaughlin points out below, an alternative solution if you're using ECMA6 (Javascript Harmony), you can keep the same value for `this` if you use arrow function syntax:

```
function enemy(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = 32;
        this.height = 32;
        this.img = new Image();
        this.ready = false;
        this.img.onload = () => this.ready = true;
        this.img.src = "images/barney.png";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! 'You can accept an answer in 11 minutes' .. meh. Lol.

Comment: @Kar - Marking answers is an integral part of using SO...

Comment: @Kar hahaha, you can accept it whenever you want, just happy to help :)

Comment: @LeeTaylor I know this? I was expressing my sadness about the wait time. smh...

Answer (score 3):

You should accept the other answer, but I'll post this for future reference.  If you're targeting ES6, you can use the fat arrow:

```
function enemy(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = 32;
    this.height = 32;
    this.img = new Image();
    this.ready = false;
    this.img.onload = () => {
        this.ready = true;
    }
    this.img.src = "images/barney.png";
}
```

Comment: Nice, I'll note that.

Comment: yup this is a fantastic point, I'll reference your post in my answer so googlers see